# Given a point on the boundary of several closed rectangles in $\mathbf{R}^n$, find an open ball contained in their union

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be a closed rectangle in $\mathbf{R}^n$ and $P$ a partition of $A$. Let $x$ be an element of $A$ which is not contained in the interior of any subrectangle of the partition. Then the set of subrectangles $R$ such that $x \in \partial R$ is non-empty. Let $R_1,\dots,R_m$ be the elements of this set, so that $x \in \bigcap_{i=1}^m \partial R_i$. Show that there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $B_\delta(x) \cap A \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^m R_i$.

Comment: You have $A= \cup_i R_i$, so this is trivially true.

Comment: No you don't. There could be more than $m$ subrectangles of the partition.

Comment: You might want to clarify the question, I presumed that the $R_1,....,R_m$ were the partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true.

Let $A$ be  the rectangle $[-1,1]^2$ with the partition $R_k$, $k=1,...,4$ being the
four $1 \times 1$ rectangles
$[0,1] \times [0,1]$, etc.

Let $x=(0,0)$ and $m=3$. Then $x \in \cap_{i=1}^m \partial R_i$ but
for all $\delta>0$, $B(x,\delta)$ contains points of $R_4$ that are not in $R_1,...,R_3$.

(Actually, a simpler example would be the interval $[-1,1]$ with the equivalent partitioning.)

---

Answer to the revised question:

By assumption, for all rectangles $R$, either $x \in \partial R$ or $x \notin \overline{R}$.

Let $\delta(R) = \inf_{r \in R} \|x-r\|$, note that if $x \in \partial R$,
then $\delta(R) = 0$ and if $x \notin \overline{R}$, then $\delta(R) >0$.

Let $I = \{ k | x \in \partial R_k \}$, and let $\delta = \min_{k \notin I} \delta(R)$, and note that $\delta >0$.

In particular, $B(x,\delta)$ intersects $R_k$ **iff** $k \in I$, hence
$B(x,\delta) \cap A = B(x,\delta) \cap \cup_k R_k = B(x,\delta) \cap \cup_{k\in I} R_k \subset \cup_{k\in I} R_k$.

Comment: I clarified the question again. I think the revised assertion is true.

Comment: @RandyRanderson: I have answered the revised question.